# Eclipse Plugin Development - Drag and Drop UI components

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop, eclipse-plugin

1. We can drag and drop UI components in Netbeans and swing code is auto
   generated.
2. We can drag and drop UI components in Eclipse to do
   Android development, and xml is auto generated.
3. We can drag and drop
   UI components in Dreamwaver and html is auto generated.
4. We can drag and drop UI components in Eclipse BIRT plugin, and xml is auto generated.

If I want to create a IDE tool like the above to drag and drop some components and have some xml code auto generated. Is there any framework I can take advantage of? 
I am thinking about eclipse plug-in development. I am wondering if there is any existing code/framework for this so that I don't have to code much to make the DND UI, properties setting and so on, but just put my business logic for xml generation into plugin.

My final work should be: an eclipse plug-in I can install into eclipse. I can drag and drop UI components and auto generate the xml according to the business logic I code into the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Graphical Editing Framework - GEF](https://eclipse.org/gef/)